# How to add a package in CygWin

Tags: logging, cygwin, syslog

Im trying to install syslogd in my CygWin setup, but for this I need to firstly add the package.

Also, once I added the package, can I copy the folder of the package and put it on an existing CygWin setup?

Answer (score 1):

`syslogd` is part of `inetutils-server package`

https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Finetutils-server%2Finetutils-server-1.9.1-2&grep=syslogd

Use cygwin setup to install `inetutils-server`, and then use `syslogd-config`
to configure it.